# bash to batch rename files with adding numbers

Tags: bash, batch-rename

I have a bunch of .jpg files with random names. I want a bash script to rename them like this:

```
basename-0.jpg
basename-1.jpg
basename-2.jpg
.
.
.
.
basename-1000.jpg
```

I wrote this:

```
n = 0;
for file in *.jpg ; do mv  "${file}" basename"${n}".jpg; n+=1;  done
```

But the problem with the above bash is that in the loop, n is considered as string so n+1 just adds another '1' to the end of newly moved file. 
Appreciate your hints.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Use `$((expression))` for arithmetic expansion in bash shell

```
n=0;
for file in *.jpg ; do mv  "${file}" basename"${n}".jpg; n=$((n+1));  done
```

Comment: How would you do adapt this answer for the case where you don't know the file extension ahead of time? Like say I have a directory of mixed extensions (that I don't know ahead of time) and I want to blindly name them all with an incrementing pattern, but keep their existing extension type.

Answer (score 4):

`Bash` can also pre/post increment/decrement variable values using arithmetic evaluation syntax like `((var++))`.

```
n=0;
for file in *.jpg ; do mv  "${file}" basename"${n}".jpg; ((n++));  done
```

Answer (score 3):

Did you want 'basename' or $(basename)?  More generalized forms are:

```
# create basename-0.jpg, basename-1.jpg, ... basename-n.jpg
e='jpg'; j=0; for f in *.$e; do mv "$f" basename-$((j++)).$e; done
```

or

```
# preserve stem: <stemA>-0.jpg, <stemB>-1.jpg, ... <stem?>-n.jpg
e='jpg'; j=0; for f in *.$e; do mv "$f" "${f%.*}"-$((j++)).$e; done
```